# Hölder's inequality for $\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{b}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{c}}$

Tags: inequality, proof-writing, proof-explanation, contest-math, holder-inequality

> Let $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$ and $a+b+c=3$. What is the minimum value of $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{b}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{c}}?$$

I've previously posted an olympiad problem where the solution was dependent on Hölder's inequality. As I'm trying to learn about how to apply this to contest problems surprisingly I couldn't find a whole lot of example problems. It seems that the general version ($\sum_{i=1}^n |x_iy_i| \leqslant (\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i|^p)^{1/p}(\sum_{i=1}^n|y_i|^q)^{1/q}$) of this is not very applicable here.

For this problem that I found it seems that the proposed solution skipped some steps while explaining it. What they had was this:

$$(\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{b}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{c}})^{1/3}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{b}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{c}})^{1/3}(a + b + c)^{1/3} \geq 1^{1/3} + 1^{1/3} +1^{1/3} = 3.$$

Now it seems that here they have $p=q=3$? How did they come up with the $LHS$ here? It's not clear and there's no explanation for it anywhere...

Comment: IMO, Jensen is much easier to apply in your case.

Comment: @trancelocation There are very many ways of this inequality proof. I think the way by using Holder is a shortest here. See my solution. I even explained all steps.

Answer (score 1):

The Holder's inequality for two sequences it's the following.

> Let $a_1$, $a_2$,..., $a_n$, $b_1$, $b_2$,..., $b_n$, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be positive numbers. Prove that:
> $$(a_1+a_2+...+a_n)^{\alpha}(b_1+b_2+...+b_n)^{\beta}\geq$$$$\geq\left(\left(a_1^{\alpha}b_1^{\beta}\right)^{\frac{1}{\alpha+\beta}}+\left(a_2^{\alpha}b_2^{\beta}\right)^{\frac{1}{\alpha+\beta}}+...+\left(a_n^{\alpha}b_n^{\beta}\right)^{\frac{1}{\alpha+\beta}}\right)^{\alpha+\beta}.$$

For positives $a$, $b$ and $c$ by Holder we obtain:  $$\left(\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}\right)^2\sum_{cyc}a\geq\left(\sum_{cyc}\sqrt[3]{\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}\right)^2\cdot{a}}\right)^3=(1+1+1)^3=27,$$
which says $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}\geq3.$$
The equality occurs for $a=b=c=1,$ which says that we got a minimal value.

Comment: Definitely nice and clear. But I still hold that Jensen is quicker :-). Nevertheless +1

Comment: @trancelocation For using Jensen you need to prove before that $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ is a convex function. I don't say that it's hard, but it's else one step. By the way, by Holder we get a solution by one easy  step.

Comment: From this point of view I agree.

Comment: Also, by AM-GM $\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}=\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{cyc}\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{a}}+a\right)-\frac{3}{2}\geq\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{cyc}3\sqrt[3]{\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}\right)^2\cdot a}-\frac{3}{2}=3.$

Comment: Sorry to bother you with this. But as the top user in [tag:contest-math] you may be able to give suggestion [in this meta discussion](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/32223/11619). The goal is to help users who want to edit contest questions so that they pass the PSQ-policies. Site politics cannot be entirely avoided there, so it may not interest you at all. But I don't want to run such a discussion behind your back either.

Answer (score 0):

In your general version, take $p = 3$ and $q = 3/2$.

Take $x_{1, 2, 3} = a^{1/3}, b^{1/3}, c^{1/3}$ and $y_{1, 2, 3} = a^{-1/3}, b^{-1/3}, c^{-1/3}$.

This gives you the minimal value.

Comment: How does one come up with correct $p$ and $q$?

Comment: Experience + some trial and error.